# Launch and call methods on WPF app from unit test project

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, integration-testing

I would like to launch a WPF app and call methods on the ViewModel to control the app for the purpose of integration testing. Something like:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
        var application = new MyApp();
        application.InitializeComponent();
        application.Run();
```

(OK, this stops the test execution at this point, presumably passing control to the WPF app. Not sure how to deal with this. Launch in a separate thread or something?)

Then I'd like to be able to get and set values on the ViewModel, something like this:

```
        application.MyViewModel.SomeProperty = "A value!";
```

The goal here is to test the WPF app in an integrated sense without resorting to WinAppDriver, White, CodedUI or anything messy like that. Ideas?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible but I have a feeling that whatever solution you roll out will be as complex as CodedUI. Consider the following use case: how to get the value of a TextBox within a StackPanel which is within a Grid which is hosted in a Dialog? Now how would you make it so that your solution will not be brittle (e.g. remove the Grid without breaking your tests).

Comment: @Ilian: the way I read the question, the OP is looking to manipulate the underlying view model object(s) directly. I.e. rather than trying to interact with the UI, he wants to bypass the UI, and just ensure that things like bindings _from_ the view model to the UI are working properly. In that context, I assume that "working" just means "no exceptions". If checking UI object properties is desired, those can be abstracted through other means. Specifics on that would be a whole 'nother question. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho That makes sense :)

Comment: You are both posing good questions. We need to totally rewrite the ViewModels and service layer to talk to a completely different back end. Solutions such as CodedUI tend to lead to slow, flaky tests and that won't cut it for the quantity of testing we'll be doing. Unit testing won't help much either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll either need a separate thread to manipulate the view model, or you'll need to execute code in the dispatcher thread to do that. I prefer the latter, but either would work. The former would require you being careful about using the dispatcher to marshal some operations to the UI thread; view model property changes don't need that, because WPF will do that automatically for you, but other things like direct calls to UI object methods — e.g. `Window.Close()` — do.

Here's an example of what you might do using the dispatcher thread to do all the testing code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestWpfApp()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var application = new App();
        Application.ResourceAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        application.InitializeComponent();
        application.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            _TestApplication(application);
        }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
        application.Run();
    });

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
}

private static async void _TestApplication(Application application)
{
    Window window = application.MainWindow;
    ViewModel viewModel = (ViewModel)window.DataContext;

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    viewModel.Text = "Hello World!";
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    window.Close();
}
```

The basic structure is to set up a thread suitable for running the WPF UI (it has to be an STA thread, and you shouldn't be messing with the unit test's thread, so creating a new thread for this purpose is required), and then in that thread, do the usual WPF setup plus queue via `InvokeAsync()` to the dispatcher a call to the main testing method, to have it start executing once the WPF code has started running.

Naturally, this example assumes a `ViewModel` class with a `Text` property, and the main window's `DataContext` property set to an instance of this `ViewModel`. In my sample program, I just bound the `Text` property to a `TextBlock.Text` property. Obviously, you could do whatever you want with your view model.

Note that I had to explicitly set `Application.ResourceAssembly`. In Visual Studio Community 2017, which is what I'm using at the moment, the unit test framework runs the text in a context where `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` returns `null`, which breaks WPF's resource loading. Setting it explicitly fixes that (I'm using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`, because I put the unit test code in the same assembly with my sample WPF program…obviously, if you keep them in different assemblies, you'd have to find the right assembly some other way).

In my testing, using `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle` in the call to `Dispatch.InvokeAsync()` wasn't strictly required. I found the `MainWindow` and `DataContext` properties initialized fine. But I prefer to explicitly wait for `ApplicationIdle`, just to make sure those have been fully initialized and that the WPF program itself is ready to start accepting whatever input you have in mind for your tests.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense to create an `App` and call `Run()` on it in a unit or integration test. You will only be able to create one `App` per `AppDomain`.

What you should do is to structure your code in a way so you don't have to test anything else than the ViewModel class alone. This means that all your application logic should be implemented in the ViewModel, or in classes that the ViewModel uses one way or another.

This is a design pattern known as Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) and it's *the* recommended design pattern to use when developing XAML-based UI applications. There is a reason for this - testing is one of them.

You'll find a lot of information about MVVM if you search for it. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) should provide a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks very much mm8, however we can't do any substantial refactoring of the code, and furthermore there are already hundreds of unit tests that won't protect us from the changes coming through. We have to completely rewrite the service layer and the viewmodels will be affected too. We need full integration testing with very broad coverage for this one.